# SWITCH-statement two case with same condition and also different condition

Tags: php, switch-statement

Hi I wonder if this could be done in switch case. Here's the example code I wanna do

```
switch($name)
case "Dog":
    $pic = "/images/itscute.jpg";
    $info ="four legs";
    break;
case "Cat":
    $pic = "/images/cat.jpg";
    $info ="four legs";
    break;
case "bird":
    $pic = "/images/bird.jpg";
    $info = "two legs";
    break;
```

Now you can see that both of dog and cat have the same value of $info.
Does it possible for me to make $info only one for both of them like this

```
switch($name)
case "Dog":
case "Cat":
    $info ="four legs";
    break;
case "bird":
    $info = "two legs";
    break;
```

then again I don't know how to place the $pic if the code like this.

EDIT : $pic at dog is not "/images/dog.jpg";

EDIT2 : added more case to be more clear question

Comment: What language? It should be added as a tag.

Comment: Added .. sorry I thought it's unnecessary bcoz I think most language have the same switch

Comment: Some languages allow fall through, but others do not. But generally in this case you would create two switch statements.

Comment: it is possible 2 switch in the same page with same $name ? I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any variables that contain the same value why use a switch at all?  Just define those variables before the switch statement.  Use the switch statement only for variables that contains different values.

**EDIT**

In that case there is no reason why you can't use 2 switch statements, like this:

```
switch(strtolower($name))
{
case "dog":
    $pic = "/images/itscute.jpg";
    break;
case "cat":
    $pic = "/images/cat.jpg";
    break;
case "bird":
    $pic = "/images/bird.jpg";
    break;
}
switch(strtolower($name))
{
case "dog":
case "cat":
    $info = "four legs";
    break;
case "bird":
    $info = "two legs";
    break;
}
```

I do recommend that you use strtolower(), like my example shows, to avoid any case problems.  You can use any number of switch statements as you need.
As for turning "dog" into "Dog's" just add the "'s" to the variable, like this:
`$name = ucwords($name . "'s");`

Comment: actually the real code much complex than this and I don't know how to explain it simply. There's 4 case. 2 of them have same variable with the same value but also with same variable and different value. The other 2 case completely different value but still same variable. And last I need to use those variable in one sentence. So if the case is Dog, sentence shows dog's.

Answer (score 2):

Since the variation of `$pic` between two cases is dependent on the value of `$name`, you can use `$name` itself:

```
switch($name) {
    case "Dog":
    case "Cat":
        $pic = "/images/" . strtolower($name) . ".jpg";
        $info ="four legs";
        break;
}
```

Comment: yeah at first I had thought like that but what if it's like my edited code? Sorry just realized that I gave the wrong example hehehe :D